# maven repository on AWS

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I want to create a simple cloud maven repository, where I would store my own artifacts (for external I will rely on the standard jcenter or mvn repos).

For object storage as far as I know Amazon provides free tier for both S3 and Glacier, but Glacier is always free while S3 only for 12 months. I was planning to try AWS just for personal experience (with possible account deletion in the future because I don't plan to pay for something I don't use).

My question - what should I use for maven repository on AWS?

Comment: [First result from a Google search](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/09/07/maven-repository-amazon-s3.html)

Comment: @stdunbar but I don't ask how to do that, I am asking what should I choose - glacier or s3

Comment: Have you read about Glacier?  For example, from the [Glacier FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/faqs/) - "Standard retrievals typically complete within 3 – 5 hours".  If you're willing to wait 3 to 5 hours every time you build then Glacier is a great solution.  If not then S3 would likely be better.  Glacier is named as it is for a reason - it is a backup solution, not a close to real time solution.

Comment: @stdunbar I see. I guess I'll try google drive as maven repo. Thanks!

Comment: Nexus or artifactory? I believe OSS version of nexus let's you use s3 as a backend. Also Glacier is not really used for this use case or designed to be.

Comment: @strongjz I thought about private repository but I did not know that nexus supported s3

Comment: It's plugin you have install yourself, https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-blobstore-s3

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used the open-source `Apache Archiva` project with S3 as backend storage by mounting S3 as file system using `S3FS-FUSE` on my `t2.micro` instance (which is provides 750hrs/month in free tier). I have detailed the solution in this [medium post](https://medium.com/@kunal.m.patil/host-low-cost-private-maven-repository-on-aws-f08f1f9266c3).

I hope this will help you to create a low-cost, private Maven Repository on AWS.

Cheers,

-Kunal